# Differences in nested flexbox between Chrome and Firefox with scrolling

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, firefox, cross-browser, flexbox

UPDATE: I'm not convinced this is a duplicate question. While the implied minimum size of flex content might be causing the issue, I still am curious why I'm getting different results in Chrome and Firefox.

I'm working on a project with nested flexboxes, where one of the nested divs has overflowing content and should scroll. I have it working just as expected in Chrome and Safari, but both Firefox and Edge behave differently.

Here's the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e3p6xk0L/4/

Also, here's the code / example inline

```css
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

.top {
  flex-basis: 40px;
  background: purple;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
}

.bottom {
  flex-basis: 40px;
  background: yellow;
}
.left {
  flex-basis: 20px;
  background: green;
}

.center {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}

.right {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  background: orange;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.right-content {
  height: 1000px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='top'>
  
  </div>
  <div class='middle'>
    <div class='left'>
    </div>

    <div class='center'>
    </div>

    <div class='right'>
      <div class='right-content'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='bottom'>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, there should always be a purple bar of fixed height at the top, and a yellow bar of fixed height on the bottom. The gray content, which overflows the right div, should only cause that right div to scroll.

Does anyone see anything obvious that I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Add `min-height: 0` to `.middle`. https://jsfiddle.net/e3p6xk0L/5/

Comment: That's close, but it still is different in Firefox vs Chrome. If you notice, in Firefox, the padding (visible as the orange border) on .right isn't visible if you scroll all the way down to the bottom.

Comment: Also, I understand why 'min-height: 0' works, but I still wonder why I'm seeing different results between Chrome and Firefox. Is there a bug in one browser's implementation?

Comment: Flexbox is a relatively new technology (CSS3). There are differences in implementation between browsers. I see the padding issue you mention. It could be a bug, it could be a different interpretation of spec language.

Comment: What's clear is this: Instead of `padding: 10px` on the parent, use `margin: 10px` on the child. That seems to work cross-browser.  https://jsfiddle.net/e3p6xk0L/7/

Comment: The answers here may also shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40030370/3597276