# Differences with padding on scroll between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

First, I'd like to say I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40001216/differences-in-nested-flexbox-between-chrome-and-firefox-with-scrolling), but it looks like a different problem.

Mine is that the scrollable element has CSS declaration like this: `padding: 2.5rem 0;`.

Chrome renders that properly. I scroll down and see that padding as "blank" space at the end, but the problem is with Firefox, where I scroll down and I can't see that "blank" area at the end.

Problem is solved if I add a `margin-bottom: 2.5rem` in FF, but it looks wrong (looks a big blank area at the bottom) in Chrome.

Here are images to explain it a bit better.

### Firefox Screenshots

[image: Top of the screen Firefox]
[image: Bottom]

### Chrome Screenshots

[image: Top of the screen Chrome]
[image: Bottom]

Here is a pen to see it in action: https://codepen.io/sebazelonka/full/PooLvgW

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After I submitted the question, I found this one: [Flexbox padding bottom fails in Firefox and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42802717/flexbox-padding-bottom-fails-in-firefox-and-safari)

Is not completely explained why is that happening, but the answer works fine and solves the problem.